# Error in artisan migration Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError : Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I solved it.
Composer require doctrine/dbal wasn't enough in Laravel 5.8 - I needed to use:
**composer require doctrine/dbal „2.9.2”** - downgrading was required in my case.

Comment: If you have a question, post a question. then you can post your answer and accept it. **Don't post your answer into your question**

Comment: Your solution worked for me: Laravel 5.8.